# How to use fixture return value in test method under a class

Tags: pytest, pytest-fixtures

I have a fixture in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)

def setup( server ):

    global ws
    if server == "Test1":
        ws = create_connection(base_class.server1)
        print("Websocket Connection Established successfully")
    elif server == "Test2":
        ws = create_connection(base_class.server2)
        print("Websocket Connection Established successfully")
    elif server == "Test3":
        ws = create_connection(base_class.server3)
        print("Websocket Connection Established successfully")

    yield     
    ws.close()
    print("Websocket Connection Closed successfully")
```

I'm using POM model and my methods are defined under a class like this in a separate file:

```
class ABC:

    def response(self, status):

    ws.send(json.dumps([3, 12345, {"status": f'{status}'}]))
```

I have a separate file test file in which test cases are defined like:

```
tc = ABC()

test_case1(setup):
    tc.response("Accepted")
```

It is throwing NameError:

```
ws.send(json.dumps([3, requestid, {"status": f'{status}'}]))

E       NameError: name 'ws' is not defined
```

How to get the value of ws from the fixture in methods defined under the class ABC?

I've also used the fixture for the class, but it is throwing an error, fixture cannot be called directly.

```
@pytest.mark.usefixture(name=setup)

class ABC:

    def response(self, status):

    ws.send(json.dumps([3, 12345, {"status": f'{status}'}]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to read more about pytest fixtures [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#how-to-fixtures).

You are not allowed to call fixtures as usual methods. They must be "requested" by tests or other fixtures.

One of the possible solutions of your problem is to pass your WebSocket connection object (`ws` variable) to `ABC` class `__init__` method.

So the code for `ABC` class will look like:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.ws = ws

    def response(self, status):
        self.ws.send(json.dumps([3, 12345, {"status": f'{status}'}]))
        # ... your code
```

`setup` fixture must yield your `ws` object. Use `yield ws` in your fixture instead of bare `yield`. Also using `global` and `autouse=True` are not necessary.

Test methods will request your `setup` fixture and pass it's value to `ABC` constructor like this:

```
def test_case1(setup):
    tc = ABC(setup)
    tc.response("Accepted")
```

Please take some time to learn more about using fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pL3b I'm new in pytest and currently learning. The solution provided by you is working if I'm calling one method in a test method but To make a flow i have to call multiple methods in one test method, 
if I'm doing this, first method is working fine, But the second method which is being called is fetching the request data of first method.

like this:-

Comment: like this:-

def test_Flow(setup):
      
       tc = ABC(setup)
       tc1 = ABC1(setup)

      tc.request("Example")
      tc.response("Accepted")
      tc1.request1("Example1")
      tc1.request2("Example2")

Comment: well, if `create_connection` returns just one-request connection then may be you should not use a fixture, but just an usual python method or a context manager.